# Unable to place database back in "Online" status

Tags: availability-groups, sql-server-2019

I am looking for some help.

I have the following setup:

1. SQL Server 2019 Enterprise running a two node AlwaysOn HA
2. One of the HA databases now has this status next to the db name "Initializing / In Recovery".
   Let's call this db "MyDB".

I am unable to resolve this despite my many attempts using various methods trying to fix it.

I have tried to perform these actions:

1. drop mydb
2. place mydb in single user mode
3. place mydb in emergency mode
4. restoring over it

No matter what I do, I get this error message "Exclusive access could not be obtained because the
database is in use."

sp_who2 shows there are 3 'sa' credentials connected to mydb.  I (sql sysadmin) tried the KILL these SPID's
but received an error saying I can only kill user processes.

Now I'm stuck with this status "Initializing / In Recovery" and unable to put mydb back in "online" status.

Anyone know how to resolve this?  Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.  I'm out of ideas
at this point.

Thanks so much!